# Select a max id on materials per date

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have my table named sup_mon:

```
genmat_id    mat_name    size     Stock_balance     date   
1              aluminum   100 m       25            2014-02-27
2              aluminum   100 m       30            2014-02-27
3              steel      100 m       60            2014-02-27
4              aluminum   100 m       30            2014-02-28
```

Here is my distinct select query:

```
select distinct mat_name, Stock_balance, date, max(genmat_id) from sup_mon where date = '2014-02-27'
```

The output was:

```
 genmat_id    mat_name    size     Stock_balance     date   
      3           steel      100 m       60         2014-02-27
```

How can I select every unique material name on its highest genmat_id on date?
like:

```
 genmat_id    mat_name    size     Stock_balance     date   
    2              aluminum   100 m       30            2014-02-27
    3              steel      100 m       60            2014-02-27
```

Comment: Do you mean its highest `Stock_balance`? Highest `genmat_id` would be 4 for aluminum, not 2, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the `max(genmat_id)` for each `mat_name` and `date`, then you could use a subquery to get the final result:

```
select t1.genmat_id,
  t1.mat_name,
  t1.size,
  t1.stock_balance,
  t1.date
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(genmat_id) genmat_id, date, mat_name
  from yourtable
  group by date, mat_name
) t2
  on t1.genmat_id = t2.genmat_id
  and t1.date = t2.date
  and t1.mat_name = t2.mat_name
where t1.date = '2014-02-27';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9783d5/1).  The subquery returns the max id for each date and `mat_name`, then you join this back to your table on the `genmat_id`, `date` and `mat_name` to get the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM sup_mon m1 LEFT JOIN sup_mon m2
 ON (m1.mat_name = m2.mat_name AND m1.genmat_id < m2.genmat_id )
WHERE m2.genmat_id IS NULL and date = '2014-02-27'
```

Note: adapted from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group).